# $filter ignored by OData when specifying additional parameters

Tags: parameter-passing, odata, filtering

When adding parameters to a call to an OData endpoint in my application like this

```
https://localhost:12345/TestServer/RequestDto
?$count=true&$orderby=TimeStamp%20desc
&$filter=(Ownername%20eq%20%27Baggins%2C%20Frodo%27)
&$skip=0&$top=26&userID=bt0388&showByAuthor=False
```

the $filter seems to be getting ignored. userID and showByAuthor are the additional parameters.

The related endpoint looks like this.

```
public class RequestDtoController : ODataController
{
    // ...
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<DocumentRequestDTO> Get(string userID, bool showByAuthor)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

It does get called with proper parameters. The data it returns is correct and complete.

I expect the OData layer to apply the filter, but it doesn't. This is the final result set:

```
{@odata.context: "https://localhost:44393/DocServer2/$metadata#RequestDto", @odata.count: 4,…}
@odata.context: "https://localhost:44393/DocServer2/$metadata#RequestDto"
@odata.count: 4
value: 
    [{ID: "dc3a6999", AuthorID: "0388", Authorname: "Wonka, Willy",…},…]
    0: 
        {ID: "dc3a6999", AuthorID: "0388", Authorname: "Wonka, Willy",…}
        Ownername: "Wonka, Willy"
        ...
    1: 
        {ID: "685b7e33", AuthorID: "Test-Owner", Authorname: "Test, Owner",…}
        Ownername: "Wonka, Willy"
        ...
    2: {ID: "8192d591", AuthorID: "0003", Authorname: "Hedgehog, Sonic",…}
        Ownername: "Baggins, Frodo"
        ...
    3: {ID: "b56b7cfc", AuthorID: "0003", Authorname: "Hedgehog, Sonic",…}
        Ownername: "Baggins, Frodo"
        ...
```

How would I need to go about fixing it?

Comment: Does it work for filter without rounded brackets? &$filter=Ownername%20eq%20%27Baggins%2C%20Frodo%27

Comment: Dude, the brackets are a part of a logical expression.

Comment: Brackets are not required in most cases for OData filter.

Comment: They don't hurt, and actually they must not be a problem, or you couldn't specify more complex filter expressions mixing "and" and "or". Anyway, the brackets do not cause the problem.